# error 1612(0x64c) while installig SharePoint server 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, installation, uninstallation

When I want to uninstall SharePoint Server 2013 I get this error :

> Error: Failed to configure:  {90150000-1015-040C-1000-0000000FF1CE} ErrorCode: 1612(0x64c).

I event try to reinstall it with running the setup again , I get the same error . 
Any idea .

Comment: Which account you are using to do the uninstallation? Ensure you are using a farm administrator account with local administrative rights.

Comment: yes i'm using the admin account .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decided to uninstall SharePoint and install it again , It's advisable to do it in fresh Windows installation.

Regarding this error code is mean the source installation is not available.

So make sure that the installation source is mounted to your drive ( or located to original installation) during SharePoint uninstalling

Check also [SharePoint 2013 installation issue](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d473e0cc-6817-4f95-963b-eca56115abdf/sharepoint-2013-installation-issue?forum=sharepointadmin)

Comment: yes Gaurravs , i ' have to add the suport . the source installation is not available.